# Error parsing JSON param in java REST

Tags: java, json, rest, maven

I have recently upgraded my REST API to use jersey 2.x and now I am unable to retrieve JSON body params the way I used to, the methods simply do not get called anymore. My guess is I'm missing a dependency to parse the JSON to a java object but I'm not too sure what i need to add in, any help appreciated.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**REST method**

```
@POST
    @Path("/users/{userId}/friends")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response followUser(@PathParam("userId") Integer myUserId, FollowUserBean user) {}
```

**FollowUserBean.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class FollowUserBean {
    public Integer friendId;

    public FollowUserBean() {}
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Consider using the same version of all Jersey artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need a JSON provider

At time of writing, Jersey 2.x integrates with the following modules to provide JSON support:

- [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy)
- [Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p)
- [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)
- [Jettison](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jettison)

### Using Jackson

See below the steps required to use Jackson as a JSON provider for Jersey 2.x:

**Adding Jackson module dependencies**

To use Jackson 2.x as your JSON provider you need to add [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.25.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To use Jackson 1.x it'll look like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson1</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Registering Jackson module**

Besides adding the dependency mentioned above, you need to register [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) (or [`Jackson1Feature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson1/Jackson1Feature.html) for Jackson 1.x) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) / [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(JacksonFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

If you don't have an [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) / [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass, you can register the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor. The specific resource, provider and feature fully-qualified class names can be provided in a *comma-separated value* of [`jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES) initialization parameter.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) provided by Jackson is [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html).

---

For more details, check the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html) about support for common media type representations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't have an Application/ResourceConfig sub-class, did jersey 1.x not need such a file to register the JSON provider?

Comment: @beerye You should create an `Application`/`ResourceConfig` sub-class. For more details, check Jersey 2.x documentation about [deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html). In Jersey 1.x, [this feature can be turned on in the `web.xml` file](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/user-guide.html#json).

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing Jersey JSON Jackson (2.x) entity providers support module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

It is recommended to use the same Jersey version in all libs.