# restful web service response with json

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I have restful web service which return list of users, i want to make response as json format but that produce the following exception:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RESTful] in context with path [/spring] threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

my restful method:

```
@GET
 @Path("all")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response getUsers(){
     UserService service = new UserService();
     List<UserBean> userBeans = service.getUsers();
     JSONObject users = new JSONObject();

     if(userBeans != null)
     {
         for(UserBean user : userBeans)
         {
             users.put("name",user.getUsername());
         }

         System.out.println(users);
         return Response.status(200).entity(users).build(); 
     }
     return Response.status(201).entity("faild").build();   
   }
```

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: Yes i use it, is there any problem about it ??

Answer (score 0):

To produce JSON with Jersey, you don't need to use the `org.json.JSONObject` class.

Ensure you have a JSON provider configured (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866558/1426227) for more details) and change your resource method to be as following:

```java
@GET
@Path("all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getUsers() {

    UserService service = new UserService();
    List<UserBean> users = service.getUsers();

    return Response.ok(users).build();
}
```