# JAX-RS unmarshal JSON sub property to hash map

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have a REST service endpoint that accepts JSON in the following format:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "properties": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}
```

Then I have this class

```
class Document {
  private String name;

  private Map<String, String> properties;

  ... setters/getters
}
```

And my REST service method

```
logger = Logger.getLogger("logger");

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response addDocument(Document document) {
  logger.info(document);
  return Response.ok(200).build();
}
```

But whenever I post the JSON above it's not unmarshalling my properties. It is always null. The name property is mapped correctly..

I would gladly accept any help/clues.Thanks!

EDIT: I did not mention that I am using glassfish 4.1 and what comes with it. I don't have any lib dependency for marshal/unmarshal.

Comment: Which library are you using to convert the POJO to JSON and vice-versa

Comment: Not using any specific lib. Using glassfish and using whatever comes with it OOB. I have restricted my app to be very flexible and deployable in any EE complaint container. Currently using glassfish 4.1 via docker

Comment: Can u post your web.xml? Make sure you you have added  com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature to true

Comment: I will test with the init-param and let you know. But as it turns out I have missed that one.

Comment: I tried the init-param, nothing changed.. The properties is still null

Comment: Anyone, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just added Gson and created custom entity provider for JSON. It works now as expected, but I would've been more glad to not handle it myself but let the container do it with whatever is configured for JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON, the Java class the JSON will be parsed into and your JAX-RS resource method look fine:

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "properties": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}
```

```java
public class Document {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addDocument(Document document) {
    ...
    return Response.ok(200).build();
}
```

Instead of using Gson as you mentioned in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39317962/1426227), you could consider using a JSON provider which integrates with Jersey. [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) is a good choice and [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s should work fine.

For details on how to use Jackson with Jersey, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866558/1426227).