# What the postman url would be for jaxrs

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs

The following URL gives 404 error http://localhost:8080/students/try
What would be the correct URL to call this api?

This is the interface

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/students")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface AddExampleResource {

    @Path("/try")
    @GET
    Response getById();
}
```

This is the implementation

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class AddExampleImplementation implements AddExampleResource {
    @Override
    public Response getById() {
        return Response.ok("student1").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add other config files: pom.xml, if you use Jersey - then JerseyConfig.

Comment: Have you looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910500/jax-rs-does-not-work-with-spring-boot-1-4-1/39912886#39912886