# How to find the complete local url of a Jaxrs API in Springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I have implemented an API but no matter what url I have tried it does not work. Here is a related post of this API. Is there any way I can make SpringBoot to print me the url of this API?

[What the postman url would be for jaxrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844306/what-the-postman-url-would-be-for-jaxrs)

Comment: Have you registered your jaxrs services? Added them to component scan, etc?