# Why ObjectNode adds backslash in in Json String

Tags: java, string, object, jackson, jackson2

Here is how I am trying to convert an object to json String

```
    ObjectNode batch = OBJECT_MAPPER.createObjectNode();
    String s = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString((triggerCommands.getCommands()));
    batch.put("commands", s);
    System.out.println("raw String= " + s);
    System.out.println("ObjectNode String = " + batch);
```

Which results in output of;

```
raw String= [{"cmdid":"a06c00d4-5b8b-4313-a8f3-5663dde0fa5b","type":"test"}]

ObjectNode String = {"commands":"[{\"cmdid\":\"a06c00d4-5b8b-4313-a8f3-5663dde0fa5b\",\"type\":\"test\"}]"}
```

I am curious to know why the String gets backslash when I add it into as value of ObjectNode. All i want is

```
ObjectNode String = {"commands":[{"cmdid":"a06c00d4-5b8b-4313-a8f3-5663dde0fa5b","type":"test"}]}
```

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815818/jackson-adds-backslash-in-json) but has no solid answer that worked.

Comment: Because a in JSON string, double quotes must be escaped. You want to value of the commands property to be a JSON array, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working in the `JsonNode` domain, you want Jackson to convert your commands to a `JsonNode`, not a `String`. Like this:

```
ObjectNode batch = OBJECT_MAPPER.createObjectNode();
JsonNode commands = OBJECT_MAPPER.valueToTree(triggerCommands.getCommands());
batch.set("commands", commands);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read some sourcecodes `toString()` method of `ObjectNode` class, calls a `TextNode.appendQuoted` then a static method `CharTypes.appendQuoted(StringBuilder sb, String content)`, this adds the ( " ) when the object is writed by `toString(),` here.. when is found a char " then it adds a backlash.
Since your key(s) is a Object array, if you check ObjectNode.put implementation its doesn't allow you add a key as array so.. it need to be parsed to a `String`

Note you wont get this.

```
ObjectNode String = {"commands":[{"cmdid":"a06c00d4-5b8b-4313-a8f3-5663dde0fa5b","type":"test"}]}
```

because the key it's not with between a " (quotes) and as a I told
ObjectNode doesn't allow you a key of type array.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String writeUnicodeString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode node = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
    node.put("field1", "Hello World");
    return node.toString();
}
This outputs:

{"field1":"Hello World"}
```