# How to avoid Jackson escaping double quotes in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am working on a project and wanted to rewrite some code written in Gson to Jackson using ObjectMapper. So I am trying to create a JSON string using some properties as below:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode objNode= objectMapper.createObjectNode();
objNode.put("identifierVal", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
objNode.put("version", "two");
List<String> namesList= new ArrayList<>();
namesList.add("test");
objNode.put("namesList", namesList.toString());
String requestObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objNode.toString());
```

**Expected result:**

```json
{
   "identifierVal":1234,
   "version":"two",
   "namesList":[
      "test"
   ]
}
```

**Actual:**

```json
"{  
        "\identifierVal\": 1234,   
        "\version\":"\two\",
"\namesList\": ["\test\"]

    }"
```

So once I create a JSON String using Jackson, it turns out it is escaping double quotes for field names and values and adding a `\` at leading and trailing spaces. So service call fails due to the escaping.

I have went through some documentation and I can understand Jackson is escaping double quotes. But is there a way to avoid escaping double quotes and adding of leading and trailing double quotes.

Any help is appreciated. BTW, I followed the links below:

[Why ObjectNode adds backslash in in Json String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394853/why-objectnode-adds-backslash-in-in-json-string)

[Jackson adds backslash in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815818/jackson-adds-backslash-in-json/41816988)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you are converting your JSON object to a String via its `toString()` method before passing it to the `objectMapper`. Change this:

```
String requestObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objNode.toString());
```

to this:

```
String requestObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objNode);
```

You also need to change this:

```
List<String> namesList= new ArrayList<>();
namesList.add("test");
objNode.put("namesList", namesList.toString());
```

to this:

```
ArrayNode namesNode = objNode.arrayNode();
namesNode.add("test");
objNode.set("namesList", namesNode);
```

and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Anyway after I update the code still it is failing because the json now looks like this:: ```{  "identifierVal":1234, "version":"two","namesList":"[ test  ]"} ``` . TO be concise. double quotes were wrapped around `[]` instead of actual string `test`.

Comment: @SantosshKumhar That's because you have another inappropriate `toString()` on your list. You didn't add a List to your node, you added a String.

Comment: How can I add list to namesNode.add();? or do you mean to add each item of list to arrayNode?

Comment: got it. I added each item of list to the arrayNode. Thanks for your help!!