# POST with jersey Java return 415 unsupported media type

Tags: java, post, jersey

So i've been struggling with this problem for a few days now. I have searched everywhere on the internet (i think?) but I cannot find the solution.

So i have this post in my glassfish server:

```
@POST
@Path("/save")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean putLocation(Location loc) {
    boolean succes = false;
    try {
        System.out.println(loc.toString());
        succes = LocationController.getController().locationSetter().saveLocation(loc);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(LocationResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return succes;
}
```

But when i post with the following cURL command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Description":"hallotesCURL","Latitude":30,"Longitude":126,"Name":"testCURL"}' http://localhost:8080/Mesta/location/save
```

I will always get error 415 unsupported media type. 
I do not use maven so I do not have a pom.xml.
Also there is not web.xml file, I think, but im not sure this was removed in the latest version of java.

This is my first time posting on here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `web.xml` deployment descriptor has not been _removed in the latest version of Java_, as you mentioned in your question. The `web.xml` became optional in Servlet 3.0 based applications because most of configurations can be made with annotations.

Comment: What kind of media type is your method supposed to produce? If it's JSON, annotate your resource method with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and add the `Accept: application/json` header to your request.

Comment: Also, ensure you have a JSON provider, such as Jackson, registered. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38866558/1426227) for more details.

Comment: But I Thought the produces and accept where only needed when i returned JSON too, or am I mistaken? I will have a second look at the jackson. I Currently have the org.json package in my libraries

Comment: Use Jackson, as described in my another answer. Your resource method returns a `boolean`. The response should contain a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: If you want jars, check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30424031/2587435)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JSON providers

The [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library doesn't integrate with Jersey. Hence the JSON won't be parsed automatically into a POJO and vice versa.

You'd better use one of the following modules to provide JSON support. All of them integrate with Jersey 2.x:

- [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy)
- [Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p)
- [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)
- [Jettison](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jettison)

### Using Jackson as a JSON provider for Jersey

I would recommend Jackson. The steps to use Jackson as a JSON provider are fully described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866558/1426227) and they are summarized below:

Add the [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.25.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all the [`jersey-media-json-jackson`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.25.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) dependencies on the classpath.

Then register the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) / [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(JacksonFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

For more details, check the Jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson).

Comment: I will try this soon! Thank you very much!